# How to use google test with free functions in anonymous namespaces?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, namespaces, googletest

I have a class that does a number of things. In order to split work into logical units, I've created a number of free functions in the anonymous namespace, as they're only used in this class.

I'm currently using gtest to unit test my classes. How can I implement unit tests for my anon namespace free functions?

Comment: You can just call the function as you would any other function, as long as the neccessary header is included. All GTest cares about is the value, for example `ASSERT_EQ(expected, calculatedFromYourFunction)`

Comment: These are defined in the .cpp file, not the header file.

Comment: Are they declared in the .cpp file too? Or just defined there?

Comment: @Cocoaster I guess you should add that to the question (and I also suggest that you should highlight in the title that you are talking about functions in anonymous namespace.)

Comment: @Cyber _'unit tests for my anon namespace free functions'_ as the OP mentions unnamed namespaces I think these are declared and defined in the TU.

Comment: Exactly, all in the TU.

Comment: @Cocoaster I would provide a wrapper class/wrapper functions that are publicly available (or just for the context of testing) and forward any parameters and return values.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: "I have a class that does a number of things." Classic violation of the single responsibility principle and hence hard to test code.

Comment: Really? What if those things are all related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google [suggests](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#testing-private-code) including the .cpp file in the test. I think it's a small price to pay to keep my source code clean.

Comment: What about double definitions of methods and functions not in anonymous namespace?

Comment: If you include source file somewhere, your linker will complain. How to deal with those problems?

Comment: I'm only going to include it in the test.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should not have functions in an anonymous namespace in a header.

That means, you want to unit test your functions in an anonymous namespace in source file.

The simplest answer is : you can't and don't those functions, since they are only available to the source file (translation unit) where they are defined.

However, you could call methods and functions, calling those functions, and test their outputs.

Another option is to move them out of anonymous namespace, and declare in the header. Then you can use some kind of unique namespace. For example :

```
// header

int someFunc();

namespace hidden {
float myFunc1(int);
}
```

Comment: And how do I test those with gtest?

Comment: @Cocoaster What do you mean with "those"?

Answer (score -1):

No one can access your function in anonymous namespace out of .cpp, so if you really need to test your function, put these functions a subtle namespace or something like that. reference implement in chrome

```
namespace xxx {
namespace subtle {
   your help functions..
}
}
```